# ¿Cómo puedo eliminar un salto de línea de un archivo text?

Tags: python

Intento eliminar un salto de línea de un archivo txt.

Tengo este archivo.txt:

```
Pedro

Juan




Elias

Lorenzo


Gato
```

Como puedes observar son saltos de línea aleatorios.
Con  `replace` elimino todos los saltos.

```
with open(r'C:\Users\youna\Desktop\archivo.txt', 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

lines = [line.replace(r'\n', ' ').replace(r'\r', '') for line in lines]

with open(r'C:\Users\youna\Desktop\archivo1.txt', 'w', encoding="utf8") as f:
    f.writelines(lines)
```

Pero obtengo esto:

```
PedroJuanEliasLorenzoGato
```

El problema no es eliminarlo como tal, sino eliminarlo y que quede un salto de línea:

```
Pedro
Juan
Elias
Lorenzo
Gato
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto? De antemano agradezco mucho su ayuda. Saludos!

Comment: `lines = [line for line in lines if line.strip()]`

Comment: Gracias, funcionó

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solo para que la pregunta no quede en el aire respondo.

Dado que quieres eliminar, no los saltos de línea sino las líneas que no tienen nada nos apoyaremos del hecho de que un string vacío es considerado como `False` (al igual que el 0).

Para determinar que la línea no contenga nada usaremos el método `.strip()` que elimina los saltos de línea y los espacios de más, por lo que, si al final nos queda una cadena vacía significa que la linea no tiene nada y por ende no la agregaremos a la nueva lista. Tu comprensión de lista quedará así:

```py
lines = [line for line in lines if line.strip()]
```

Donde la línea solo se agregará si resulta ser una cadena con cualquier valor, es decir, ser un valor *truthy* (cualquier tipo de dato **no** vacío y el 1)

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar el [método `.replace(antiguo, nuevo)`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_replace.asp) para reemplazar el salto (`\n`) por una cadena vacía (`""`):

```
archivo = 'C:\Users\youna\Desktop\archivo.txt'
open (archivo,"r")
archivoSinSaltos = archivo.replace("\n","")

print (archivoSinSaltos)
```

Comment: Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. _Esta respuesta se reportó como de baja calidad debido a su extensión y contenido._